# Android - Activity onStart

Tags: android, android-activity

I have this MainActivity which launches when I start the application, and what I know that only then the onCreate will be called, and after that onStart will be called.
Is there anyway to know if onStart has been called, without onCreate being called first?
I mean if I press back button from the second activity, then only onStart will be called, how can figure this out? Or maybe there's a way of knowing the position of one activity in the the whole activity stack?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I have this MainActivity, it will either send you to LoginActivity, or if you are already logged, it will send you to ProfileActivity. When I press back in ProfileActivity i want to be able to go to home, and not the MainActivity. I know how to override back button to act like home button, but problem is that I have other activities, and if I press back on ProfileActivity I only want it to act like home if no other activities are in onPause.

SOLVED:

```
@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    if(counter == -1){
        finish();   
    }
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    counter--;
}
```

I'll give my creds to ArcDare for giving me the idea of implementing counters, thanks!

Comment: What about using on pause and on resume?
And please be specific, what do you want to do actually?

Comment: You might get more help if you explain your question better. But as per my understanding you dont want to call onCreate when you click on back button, is it!. I think instead of using onStart() can you use onResume()? It may be solved your problem.

Comment: I have this MainActivity, it will either send you to LoginActivity, or if you are already logged, it will send you to ProfileActivity. When I press back in ProfileActivity i want to be able to go to home, and not the MainActivity. I know how to override back button to act like home button, but problem is that I have other activities, and if I press back on ProfileActivity I only want it to act like home if no other activities are in onPause.

Comment: Store your logged data into sharedPreference and when application will run then check is sharedPreference has data or not, if sharedPreference has data then call ProfileActivity.  else loginActivity. And after doing this you dont need to override onBackPressed() bcoz if sharedPreference has data then it will open ProfileActivity.  and when you click on back button then it will directly go to the home page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is related to activity lifecycle.

1. `onCreate()` gets called only when the activity starts either your app does it or after the process is being killed.
2. The activity goes in `Pause` state when another activity comes over it. In this case when user pressed back button then `onResume()` get's called.
3. The activity goes in `Stop` state when activity is not in foreground.

`The foreground lifetime of an activity` happens between a call to onResume() until a corresponding call to onPause(). During this time the activity is in front of all other activities and interacting with the user. An activity can frequently go between the resumed and paused states -- for example when the device goes to sleep, when an activity result is delivered, when a new intent is delivered -- so the code in these methods should be fairly lightweight.

In this case the acitivity goes in `onRestart() -> onStart()`.

For detailed description over activity lifecycle refer this [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

**To your specific problem as you mentioned in Comments above:**

Once you are done with MainActivity/LoginActivity finish() it, then they will not be in your activity stack and now if there is no activity in your stack then on pressing back button it will go to home screen or it there are then it will navigate to that screen. Now you don't need to override back button.

Answer (score 0):

You can always put DEBUG messages in your onStart() and onCreate() and see when they are called. Also consult the documentation about the [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) of the Activity.

Answer (score 0):

> how can figure this out?

Just create to static variables:

```
int timesOnCreate=0;
int timesOnStart=0;
```

And increase them in their bodies:

```
public void onCreate(){
timesOnCreate++;
(...)
}

(...)

public void onStart(){
timesOnStart++;
(...)
}
```

Like this you'll just have to check the vars.

Comment: What I want to know is when onStart gets called, without onCreate being called before that.

Comment: Ok, then you could use a Toast that shows you where you invoke the methods. Just add, on your onCreate:
         Context context = getApplicationContext();

  CharSequence text = "onCreate has been Called";
  int length= Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
  Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, length);
  toast.show();

Then do the same with onStart:

 Context context = getApplicationContext();

  CharSequence text = "onStart has been Called";
  int length= Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
  Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, length);
  toast.show();

Comment: Oh my god, this had no format. I'll write another answer so it is understable.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
private static onCreateCalled;
private static onStartCalled;

onCreate(){
   onCreateCalled = true;
   onStartCalled = false;   
}

onPause(){
  onCreateCalled = false;
  onStartCalled = false;
}

onStart(){
   onStartCalled = true;        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is ***you*** who wants to know when are Called, you can toast them when invoked:

```
public void onCreate(){
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "onCreate has been Called";
    int length= Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, length);
    toast.show();
(...)
}
(...)
public void onStart(){
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "onStart has been Called";
    int length= Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, length);
    toast.show();
(...)
}
```

If you want ***your application*** to know it, you can play with the variables we talked before, so you check them and then turn them =0 again, so they'll act like flags; Is the flag !=0? It has been called. Is it =0? It hasn't been called.